# why does jquery proxy have this?

Tags: jquery, proxy

in jquery proxy fn

```
proxy: function( fn, context ) {
    var tmp, args, proxy;

    if ( typeof context === "string" ) {
        tmp = fn[ context ];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }

    // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec
    // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Simulated bind
    args = slice.call( arguments, 2 );
    proxy = function() {
        return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( slice.call( arguments ) ) );
    };

    // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
    proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++;

    return proxy;
},
```

what is the main usage for the syntax 2, (context, string)?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yv8hY/1/ - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/#example-1

Comment: See the second example on the documentation for jQuery.proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ensuring the passed in `context` variable is present as an argument (and is also a string) before assigning the data within the `fn` object with a key of `context` to the `tmp` variable.

Without doing this, if we just called `$.proxy(fn)` with no `context` argument, the `fn` variable would end up as `undefined` and the proxy function itself would return `undefined` instead of simply ignoring the `context` variable altogether and processing as if it weren't passed in in the first place.